# Why is this class abstract?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, abstract, virtual-functions

I'm trying to create an implementation of a LinkedList that represents polynomials. The Linked list is going to be a list of "Term"s. A term is an implementation of Data (which is an abstract class with methods: compareTo() and toString()). The Polynomial class has a variable called head which I am trying to initialize as a Term. My compiler is saying that I "cannot declare member of abstract type: Term", but I did not think Term was abstract because it is an implementation of Data (the abstract class). If you guys could take a look at this and let me know of any huge red flags I'm missing, I would greatly appreciate it.
Collection.h:

```
  class Data {
  public:
  virtual ~Data() {}

virtual int compareTo(Data * other) const = 0;

virtual string toString() const = 0;
};

class Term : public Data { 
public:
int coefficient;
string variable1;
int exponentX;
string variable2;
int exponentY;
Term * next;

Term(int coeff, string var1, int exp1, string var2, int exp2, Term * next) : 
    coefficient(coeff), 
    variable1(var1),
    exponentX(exp1),
    variable2(var2),
    exponentY(exp2),
    next(next) {};

string convertInt(int number) {
    stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
    ss << number;//add number to the stream
    return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
}

int compareTo(Term * term) {
    if(this->exponentX > term->exponentX) {
    return 1;
    }
    else if(this->exponentX < term->exponentX) {
    return -1;
    }
    else {
        if(this->exponentY > term->exponentY) {
        return 1;
        }
        else if(this->exponentY < term->exponentY) {
        return - 1;
        }
        else {
        return 0;
        }
    }
}
string toString() {
    stringstream s;
    int * current = &this->coefficient;
    if(*current == 1 || *current == -1) {
    }
    else if(coefficient != 0) {
    s << convertInt(coefficient);
    }
    else { return s.str(); }
    if(variable1 != "" && this->exponentX != 0) {
    s << variable1;
    s << convertInt(exponentX);
    }
    if(variable2 != "" && this->exponentY != 0) {
    s << variable2;
    s << convertInt(exponentY);
    }
return s.str();
}   
};
```

Also, here is implementation of LinkedList. There are some other methods in there, but they don't seem to be giving any issues.

LinkedList.cpp:

```
 class Polynomial : public LinkedList { 
public:
Term head;

Polynomial() {
this->head = NULL;
}

~Polynomial() {
Term * current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        Term * next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are overriding virtual methods, you have to match the function signatures *precisely*. The return type may vary in accordance with covariance rules, but the parameter types must be exactly the same.

In the base class `Data` function `compareTo` is declared as

```
virtual int compareTo(Data * other) const
```

In the derived class `Term` it is declared as

```
int compareTo(Term * term)
```

Firstly, the parameter type is different. Secondly, the `const` is missing.

This means that you wrote a completely unrelated function in the derived class. It does not override the base class's pure virtual function. Since the base pure virtual function remain non-overriden, class `Term` is still abstract.

In `Term` you have to declare your function precisely as

```
int compareTo(Data * other) const
```

I assume that you expect to use `compareTo` in `Term` only for `Term`-to-`Term` comparisons. But in this design you'll have to either receive `Data` as an argument and then cast it to `Term`, or use the double-dispatch technique.

P.S. On top of that you declare a `Term` object as a member `head` of your `Polynomial` class and then later use it as if it is a *pointer*

```
Term * current = head;
```

This makes no sense at all. If you want your `head` to be a pointer, declare it as a pointer. If you want it to be an object, then stop using it as a pointer. Either this or that.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the [C++11 `override` identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final).

Comment: @AndreyT Thank you for your help! I would upvote, but I don't have reputation for it yet. I didn't understand why the pointer was doing that. That alone removed a chunk of the errors I was getting.

Comment: @user1527482: Turning the `head` declaration into a pointer will also *hide* the original error (about abstract class). However, it will resurface anyway in some other place.